# Eigen 3 - Backwards compatibility

Tags: backwards-compatibility, eigen3

Currently I need to resort in a sparse solver for a project. However I use an old version of Eigen3 on Ubuntu 12.04 (during the thesis I avoid unnecessary updates/upgrades), which means that all the information that I find online cannot be used at the moment because of my outdated version, while the few unsupported tools of my version are very hard to use (weird compilation errors - e.g. with unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra)

I think that I should upgrade to the last stable version, however it is very critical that I will be able to replicate the numbers of all the experiments that I got with the current outdated version. Is Eigen safe when it comes to backwards compatibility?

Eigen is also a dependency for PCL that I'm using, so I'm not sure if this complicates things. Everything is installed with apt-get. Linking to a new version of Eigen locally for experimentation is not possible, because PCL complains and expects to find Eigen installed globally (i.e. in /usr/local/include).

Answer (score 0):

Eigen is source (API) and binary (ABI) backward compatible (of course, except for unsupported/*). However, the numerical results might be slightly different due to different rounding errors, but that's already the case when, e.g., enabling/disabling SSE or OpenMP.

Since Eigen is header only, it is very easy to try the newest version.